# Azure Reserved IPs - any way to allocate a block of contiguous IPs?

Tags: powershell, azure

I've set-up a subscription and had the quota of reserved IPs increased to 100.  I'd like to reserve a block of contiguous IPs, but haven't found any documentation to do this from Microsoft.

The second-best option would be to have IPs at least within a closer range, i.e. 140.40* or 140.45*

Right now, the IPs I am getting are all over the place:

104.40.83.192
23.100.37.214
23.100.35.130
104.45.210.85
So, is there any way to allocate a block of contiguous IPs, or to at a minimum get a set of like IPs?

Powershell code I am using to reserve the IP/Set to a VM:

```
    New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName $ReservedIPName –Label “ReservedLabel” –Location $location
    Get-AzureReservedIP
    New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmName -InstanceSize $instanceSize -ImageName (Get-AzureVMImage -ImageName $imageName).ImageName| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUsername $adminLogin -Password $adminPasswd| New-AzureVM -ServiceName $vmName –ReservedIPName $ReservedIPName -Location $location
```

Answer (score 0):

That way no. We just allocate you IPs from a pool. What you can do though is ask Support if they have a way to do it for you. I'm not sure if it's possible, but you can ask and they will guide you to the correct place/procedure to go through if it is.